# SQL not Returning Desired Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to generate result from a SQL, but i am not getting desired results.
[image: this is the result of following query]

above image is the result of following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        U.USERID, U.shopName, U.image, P.PID 
        FROM users U, products P 
        WHERE P.USERID=U.USERID 
        GROUP BY U.USERID 
        ORDER BY P.PID DESC
```

Now what i want to do is that there is another record for USERID 2 and 3 with PID 3 and 5 respectively,  let me show you the image

[image: Full Table]

I want to retrieve latest record entered in the table but with distinct USERID

### e-g i want to retrive this

### userid | shopname | image | PID

### 3 | shop name | image | 5

### 4 | shop name | image | 4

### 2 | shop name | image | 3

any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

select * from "table" grou by ID and order by Desc

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below, Do group by with PID.

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.USERID, U.shopName, U.image, P.PID FROM users U, products P WHERE P.USERID=U.USERID GROUP BY P.PID ORDER BY P.PID DESC
```

Comment: i always tried this thing but this does returns repeated USERID's :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem, but perhaps the following query solves your problem:

`SELECT U.USERID, U.shopName, U.image, P.PID 
FROM users U, products P 
WHERE P.USERID=U.USERID
AND P.PID in (select min(p2.pid) from products p2 where u.userid = p2.userid)`

A word of warning: it might be more efficient to use the `ORDER BY` trick and filter the results externally.

Comment: it only returned a single record :(

Comment: Ups, i had a mistake in the query. it said `p.userid` in the nested query but it should have been `p2.userid`. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it just gave me the inverse result of my own query.

Comment: If that is the case you can try to change either `min` to `max` or `in` to `not in` ... but I have to confess I think I did not fully understand what you really want to achieve. Perhaps you could add to your post the content of the two tables separately.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance, but i have done the task using some PHP coding. :)